# Mongoose .find string parameters

Tags: node.js, string, mongodb, mongoose

I have a function using mongoose to query my database. The connection already works. However, if I do not use actual strings, but instead string variables, the .find returns an undefined object (i.e. it doesn't find anything). Here is the code:

```
function getUser(obj, callback){
    console.log("obj.key: " + obj.key[0].toString() + ":" + obj.value[0].toString());
    var first = "name.first";
    console.log("first: " + first);
    var second = "nicholas";
    console.log("second: " + second);
    User.findOne({first:second}, 'name telephone address1 address2 city state zip country', function(err, user){//nothing can be found when not directly using a string!!!
        console.log("got this user: " + user.name);

    });
}
```

this does not work, however, if I replace the line with .find with this, it does:

```
User.findOne({"name.first":"nicholas"}, 'name telephone address1 address2 city state zip country', function(err, user){
```

I've never seen anything like this before. Normally a string is a string and it will work no matter what you do with it. 
Any ideas what might be wrong?

p.s.the console.logs:

> obj.key: name.first:nicholas
>  first: name.first
>  second:
>   nicholas
>  error at: console.log("got this user...cannot read
>   property 'name' of null.

Comment: it looks like the key part of the JSON object is the problem. I can use a variable for the value part, but the key part has to be a string and not a variable for some reason. I've also tried this with a flat object (firstname instead of name.first), but I get the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [JavaScript object literal syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_literals), in the notation `{first:second}`, `first` is a *property name*, not a *variable* subject to expansion.

To quote the doc:

> Object property names can be any string, including the empty string. **If the property name would not be a valid JavaScript identifier, it must be enclosed in quotes.** Property names that would not be valid identifiers also cannot be accessed as a dot (.) property, but can be accessed and set with the array-like notation("[]").

---

Given you question:

- `User.findOne({"name.first":"nicholas"}, ...)` works as your property is named `name.first` (this is a MongoDB property using the [dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation))
- `User.findOne({first:"nicholas"}, ...)`  does not work as you are refering to a field named `first`

You may achieve the desired result by initializing your object field using `[]`:

```
query = {}
query[first] = "nicholas"
//    ^^^^^
//  this is a variable
User.findOne(query, ...)
```

Please note as this is a recurrent need, ECMA 6 has [object literal computed property keys](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:object_literals#object_literal_computed_property_keys) allowing you to write something *like* that:

```
{ [first]: "nicholas" }
```

AFAIK, as of today this is not much supported by the major JS implementation though.

Comment: Cool! that actually makes a lot of sense though I have to admit that I would not have come up with that on my own. {[first]:"nicholas"} doesn't seam to work, but maybe I'm using it wrong, but creating an object as an array for the query works a charm and is exactly what I wanted to do anyway, so thanks for that :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `[]` notation to use a variable as an object key:

```
var first = "name.first";
var second = "nicholas";
var query = {};
query[first] = second;
User.findOne(query, 'name telephone address1 address2 city state zip country', function(err, user){
    console.log("got this user: " + user.name);
});
```