# Mongoose: Pushing an object to an array of objects

Tags: mongoose, push, subdocument

I've looking over various other similar questions and just can't seem to make sense of why I can't push an object of just 2 numbers to an array.

The examples I've tried copying from are these:
[Mongoose findOneAndUpdate: update an object in an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51226544/mongoose-findoneandupdate-update-an-object-in-an-array-of-objects)
[How to push an array of objects into an array in mongoose with one call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963684/how-to-push-an-array-of-objects-into-an-array-in-mongoose-with-one-call)
[Mongoose .find string parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30350305/mongoose-find-string-parameters)

And the official docs: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoosearray_MongooseArray-push

This is my schema

```
const BatchSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },

  envRecord: {
    type: [{
      tmp: {
        type: Number
      },
      hum: {
        type: Number
      }
    }],
  }

});

BatchSchema.plugin(timestamp);

const Batch = mongoose.model('Batch', BatchSchema);
module.exports = Batch;
```

My push code looks like this:

```
 server.put('/batches/:title', async(req, res, next) => {
    //Check for JSON
    if (!req.is('application/json')) {
      return next(new errors.InvalidContentError("Expects 'application/json'"));
    }

    try {
      const batch = await Batch.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _title: req.params.title },
        req.body,
        batch.envRecord.push({ tmp, hum })
      );
      res.send(200);
      next();
    } catch(err) {
      return next(new errors.ResourceNotFoundError(`There is no batch with the title of ${req.params.title}`));
    }
  });
```

Using post man I'm using PUT to send the following JSON in the body

```
http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:3000/batches/titleGoesHere
{
    "tmp": 20,
    "hum": 75
}
```

What I'm kind of confused by is that all of the examples I've found are using `$push` but the official docs don't seem to have that anymore and instead are using `MongooseArray.prototype.push()` which is why I was trying to reference mine as `batch.envRecord.push({ tmp, hum })`

Yes I have checked if the title matches and the batch can be found with

```
server.get('/batches/:title', async(req, res, next) => {

    try {
      const batch = await Batch.findOne({title: req.params.title});
      res.send(batch);
      next();
    } catch(err) {
      return next(new errors.ResourceNotFoundError(`There is no batch with the title of ${req.params.title}`));
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `batch.envRecord.push({ tmp, hum })` as a third argument of `findOneAndUpdate` which represents query options object. So you need to push the object only after `findOneAndUpdate` is executed and `save` it. The downside on this approach is that 2 queries are executed:

```
const batch = await Batch.findOneAndUpdate(
  { title: req.params.title },
  req.body   
).exec();

batch.envRecord.push({ tmp, hum });
batch.save();
```

That is why using `$push` is a preferred approach.

Comment: so `$push` is not a something in mongoose and is part of something else? How would that look in this instance? I had tried that several times without success. Granted the examples were from 2014/15 so maybe the syntax has changed since?